# Finite algorithm for guessing positive integer

Tags: logic, puzzle

**Question**: $A$ and $B$ play a game. $B$ chooses a positive integer in mind. $A$ can ask questions of the form "Is your number $x$?" for any $x$ that $A$ wants. Does $A$ have a finite algorithm to correctly guess $B$'s number?

**Answer 1**: **Yes**. $A$ sequentially asks the question for $1,2,3,\dots$, so no matter which number $y$ that $B$ chooses, $A$'s algorithm will finish in $y$ steps.

**Answer 2**: **No**. No matter what $A$ asks, $B$'s strategy is to always answer no. So $A$'s algorithm cannot terminate.

Obviously, one of these answers must be wrong. But which one?

Comment: $B$ chooses the number before $A$ even asks, so they can't always answer no.

Comment: All algorithms are finite. This is the most important difference between program and algorithm. Program is a better word here or finite should be omitted.

Comment: @VarunVejalla But even if $B$ always answers no, at no point can $A$ say for sure that $B$ has lied!

Comment: I was under the assumption that $B$ can't lie. If they can, then it could go on for forever.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer 1 is correct, and Answer 2 is incorrect.

According to the specification of this problem, $B$ is to choose a number and stick to that. So, $A$ will eventually hit on that number using the $1,2,3,...$ strategy.

Of course, $B$ can lie and say "no" even if $A$ guesses the number $B$ has in mind. But that does not mean that $A$ did not pick correctly. The question is not whether $A$ has a strategy that will, after some finite guesses, tell $A$ what the number is. The question is simply:

> Does A have a finite algorithm to correctly guess B's number?

So that has nothing to do with $A$ knowledge, but simply about the fact whether $A$ spoke out the number that $B$ picked.

Here, by the way, is another interesting scenario. Suppose that $A$'s strategy is predictable, as the $1,2,3,..$ strategy is. With that, $B$ can anticipate what $A$ is going to ask and always pick a new number that $A$ is not going to ask, and hasn't asked before either.  In this scenario, $B$ will never have to lie and can always confidently say "No" forever. However, now we are describing a game that is *different* from the original (that is, if $B$ does this, then $B$ is cheating). For the *original* game, where $B$ chooses a number *once*, and then has to *stick* with it, there is a finite winning strategy for $A$

In sum, as long as we stick to the rules of the game, then the answer to the question:

> Does A have a finite algorithm to correctly guess B's number?

is yes. And the reasoning given by Answer 1 is exactly correct.